# Hibernate saveOrUpdate() nullPointerException thrown on every second update

Tags: hibernate

I am having a problem with some hibernate code.  I am calling the saveOrUpdate() method and every second time I try to do an update I get a NullPointerException.  First time it works, second time it doesn't, third time it does.  This is happening on updates.  I am not refreshing the page, republishing the server, nothing.  Here is my code.  The exception is being thrown on the session.getTransaction().commit(); line.

```
Session session = getSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(com);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I have tried to do session.flush() and session.close() after the commit but it doesn't help.

Any help would be really appreciated.

And here is the stack trace....

```
[16/09/09 12:14:06:817 BST] 00000027 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: JetspeedContainer. Exception thrown : java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBData.clearItem(DBData.java:431)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBDataSetImpl.clearItem(DBDataSetImpl.java:3528)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.clearParameters(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3401)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.resetStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2369)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2020)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:1972)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:497)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:94)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:87)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:218)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2289)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2242)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2542)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:92)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:232)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:297)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
at com.fmr.fc.portlet.communications.dao.impl.HibernateCommunicationsDAOImpl.createCommunication(HibernateCommunicationsDAOImpl.java:128)
at com.fmr.fc.portlet.communications.CommunicationsAdminPortlet.processAction(CommunicationsAdminPortlet.java:168)
at org.apache.jetspeed.factory.JetspeedPortletInstance.processAction(JetspeedPortletInstance.java:97)
at org.apache.jetspeed.container.JetspeedContainerServlet.doGet(JetspeedContainerServlet.java:258)
at org.apache.jetspeed.container.JetspeedContainerServlet.doPost(JetspeedContainerServlet.java:396)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:989)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:501)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:464)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:639)
at org.apache.jetspeed.container.invoker.ServletPortletInvoker.invoke(ServletPortletInvoker.java:273)
at org.apache.jetspeed.container.invoker.ServletPortletInvoker.action(ServletPortletInvoker.java:148)
at org.apache.pluto.PortletContainerImpl.processPortletAction(PortletContainerImpl.java:164)
at org.apache.jetspeed.container.JetspeedPortletContainerWrapper.processPortletAction(JetspeedPortletContainerWrapper.java:133)
at org.apache.jetspeed.pipeline.valve.impl.ActionValveImpl.invoke(ActionValveImpl.java:148)
at org.apache.jetspeed.pipeline.JetspeedPipeline$Invocation.invokeNext(JetspeedPipeline.java:167)
at org.apache.jetspeed.container.ContainerValve.invoke(ContainerValve.java:109)
at org.apache.jetspeed.pipeline.JetspeedPipeline$Invocation.invokeNext(JetspeedPipeline.java:167)
at com.fmr.fcpf.util.PageHistoryValve.invoke(PageHistoryValve.java:161)
at org.apache.jetspeed.pipeline.JetspeedPipeline$Invocation.invokeNext(JetspeedPipeline.java:167)
at org.apache.jetspeed.profiler.impl.ProfilerValveImpl.invoke(ProfilerValveImpl.java:248)
at org.apache.jetspeed.pipeline.JetspeedPipeline$Invocation.invokeNext(JetspeedPipeline.java:167)
at org.apache.jetspeed.security.impl.LoginValidationValveImpl.invoke(LoginValidationValveImpl.java:159)
at org.apache.jetspeed.pipeline.JetspeedPipeline$Invocation.invokeNext(JetspeedPipeline.java:167)
at org.apache.jetspeed.localization.impl.LocalizationValveImpl.invoke(LocalizationValveImpl.java:170)
at org.apache.jetspeed.pipeline.JetspeedPipeline$Invocation.invokeNext(JetspeedPipeline.java:167)
at org.apache.jetspeed.security.impl.AbstractSecurityValve$1.run(AbstractSecurityValve.java:138)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:215)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:645)
at org.apache.jetspeed.security.JSSubject.doAsPrivileged(JSSubject.java:179)
at org.apache.jetspeed.security.impl.AbstractSecurityValve.invoke(AbstractSecurityValve.java:132)
at org.apache.jetspeed.pipeline.JetspeedPipeline$Invocation.invokeNext(JetspeedPipeline.java:167)
at org.apache.jetspeed.container.url.impl.PortalURLValveImpl.invoke(PortalURLValveImpl.java:67)
at org.apache.jetspeed.pipeline.JetspeedPipeline$Invocation.invokeNext(JetspeedPipeline.java:167)
at org.apache.jetspeed.capabilities.impl.CapabilityValveImpl.invoke(CapabilityValveImpl.java:126)
at org.apache.jetspeed.pipeline.JetspeedPipeline$Invocation.invokeNext(JetspeedPipeline.java:167)
at org.apache.jetspeed.pipeline.JetspeedPipeline.invoke(JetspeedPipeline.java:146)
at org.apache.jetspeed.engine.JetspeedEngine.service(JetspeedEngine.java:222)
at org.apache.jetspeed.engine.JetspeedServlet.doGet(JetspeedServlet.java:242)
at org.apache.jetspeed.engine.JetspeedServlet.doPost(JetspeedServlet.java:269)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:989)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:930)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
at com.fmr.fc.common.authentication.ERLoginFilter.doFilter(ERLoginFilter.java:216)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
at com.fmr.fc.common.authentication.FCLoginFilter.doFilter(FCLoginFilter.java:279)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
at com.fmr.fc.common.authentication.CommonPortalFilter.doFilter(CommonPortalFilter.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:761)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:673)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:498)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:464)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:744)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1439)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:112)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:383)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1469)
```

Answer (score 1):

What Oracle JDBC driver version are you using?

This was a known problem with ojdbc14.jar for Oracle 9. Download the latest JDBC driver for your platform and it should go away.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have seen that problem when I googled the error earlier but I am using Oracle 10, Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.2.0".

This issue is happening when I do a delete(), save(), update(), saveOrUpdate() and whether I do it by manually getting the session and beginning the transaction or by using hibernateTemplate.

Comment: Are you SURE that's the version you're using? Judging by the stack trace, you're running WebSphere; it can have its own copy of the driver tucked in somewhere. At any rate, the newest Oracle 10 version is 10.2.0.4 and it had quite a few bugs fixed: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/readme_jdbc_10204.html Consider upgrading to it and see if it helps

Comment: On further investigation and after a complete search of my machine there is a version of 9.0.2 in C:\IBM\SDP70\runtimes\base_v61\lib but that is not the one that is in my java build pat in RAD.  When I copy version 10.0.2 over to lib my server throws rollback exceptions when it publishes the project....

Comment: I can't help you with WebSphere troubleshooting, unfrotunatelly - I've washed my hands of that abomination many years ago. It should be possible to explicitly specify a particular jar dependency in your app deployment descriptor / configuration. The bottom line here is - this is not in any way a Hibernate issue.

Comment: well, I managed to get the RAD issue sorted but I still get the every second update problem.  I read a post on a forum that says if you change the statement cache size to 0 then it will work and it does.  I would prefer if I didn't have to do this but it will have to do for now.  I would like if the jar could be updated but that is not a decision I can make, need to wait a week until our expert returns form holidays!